# How to add href using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm making adrop down menu using the following jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // executed after the page has finished loading
   $('#navigationMenu li .normalMenu').each(function(
      $(this).before($(this).clone().removeClass().addClass('hoverMenu'));
   });
   $('#navigationMenu li').hover(function(){    
      $(this).find('.hoverMenu').stop().animate({marginTop:'0px'},200)
   },
   function(){
     $(this).find('.hoverMenu').stop().animate({marginTop:'-25px'},200);
   });
});
```

I need help adding the href from ONLY the clones created.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove href when you are cloning them using `.removeAttr()`

```
  $(this).before($(this).clone().removeClass().addClass('hoverMenu').removeAttr('href'));
```

to add href you can use .attr()

```
 $(this).before($(this).clone().removeClass().addClass('hoverMenu').attr('href','#'));
```

Comment: i need help with solving a problem in the following file [link](http://www.2shared.com/file/xO6u2LXC/Navigation_Menu.html)

Answer (score 0):

To add the `href` attribute use `attr`:

```
$(this).before(
   $(this)
    .clone()
    .addClass('hoverMenu')
    .attr('href', 'http://google.com')
);
```

Reference:

> ### [`.attr( attributeName, value )`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)
>
> ---
>
> **Description**: Set one or more attributes for the set of matched elements.
>
> - `attributeName`
>
>   Type: `String`
>
>   The name of the attribute **to set**.
> - `value`
>
>   Type: String or Number
>
>   A **value to set** for the attribute.